# How do I prevent willDisplay cell: from being called when I reload a UICollectionView's data?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an animation being called on a cell (to shirk fast and grow slowly). The animation is being done in `willDisplay cell:`. The problem I have is that whenever I reload the data after fetching more from the server, willDisplay cell: is called on all visible cells. This causing all visible cells to shrink and grow. Is there a way to call reload data only on the newly fetched items?

The current call to the animation is.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView.isDragging {
           (cell as! AnimatedView).shrinkAndGrow(toScale: STANDARD_SHRINK_SCALE, withDuration: STANDARD_GROW_DURATION)
        }

    }
```

My current workaround is

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func reloadData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: { self.reloadData()})
        {_ in completion() }
    }
}
```

In the fetching method

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.orders.append(contentsOf: orders)
    self?.shouldAnimate = false
    self?.collectionView.reloadData { [weak self] in
        self?.shouldAnimate = true
    }
}
```

How I am handling

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if shouldAnimate, collectionView.isDragging {
       (cell as! AnimatedView).shrinkAndGrow(toScale: STANDARD_SHRINK_SCALE, withDuration: STANDARD_GROW_DURATION)
    }

}
```

If anyone has a way of doing this without using a flag, please let me know. Flags making things cluttered and cause wars.

Comment: What about cells that appear/reappear as a result of scrolling the collection view?

Comment: @rmaddy They appear fine scrolling on either direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var shouldAnimate = false 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
   if shouldAnimate { 
     (cell as! AnimatedView).shrinkAndGrow(toScale: STANDARD_SHRINK_SCALE, withDuration: STANDARD_GROW_DURATION)  
   }
}
```

And change `shouldAnimate` after your first reload

Comment: Was looking for a way to do it without a flag as it would require more complexity. I have something like this and will keep it for now.